# Joomla-3 Change menu-item after clicking

Tags: menu-item

I want to create a Joomla menu-item that changes its name after it has been clicked on and I want to be abled to insert code (in  php??) in a if then else style (if name = oldname then  elseif name = newname then).

Comment: I would suggest using jQuery for something like this

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for inserting php code after jQuery/Javascript event. If you want to change menu item name after click you should work on this file:

`/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default_component.php`

You should use [Template Override](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) to create alternative layout for `mod_menu`. Then in `default_component.php` (or your new layout) add code working as follows:

- If current menu item is item you want modify add a marker in JSession
- Check if current item that mod_menu will display in default_component.php is item you want to modify
- If this is the item and there is a marker in JSession (if the item was clicked) change its name

Alternative way is to use Cookie as a marker and add/create it when Java Script Click event is triggered on menu item you want to modify (so basically you omit first step and change last one)

### Few useful functions:

Get current menu item (menu item for current page):

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive()
```

Get current menu item ID:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('Itemid')
```